# SQL Server on Linux: ODBC connection from Windows works, application does not

Tags: sql-server, linux, connection, odbc, windows-client

I have a test environment with a Linux Ubuntu 16.04 'server', running MS SQL Server 17, where the company database is hosted. My client machine is a Windows 7 machine.

- I have managed to import the database into the Linux server, and am able to create and successfully test an ODBC connection from the Windows client.
- SQL Server Management Studio on the Windows PC is able to create/drop tables, create users, objects and so forth on the SQL Server instance on Linux.

I am connecting as follows in VB 6.0

```
Dim rec1 As ADODB.Recordset 
Set rec1 = New ADODB.Recordset 
rec1.Open "Select * from tblSysReg", gstrDefaultDB, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
```

- gstrDefaultDB is the string containing the name of the ODBC registered and tested connection.
- The connection test credentials are: system administrator (sa) and password.
- The connection is set to use SQL Server Authentication

This is where the error is generated as follows:

- automation error code -2147217843

However, when I run the software program from the Windows client, it is unable to 'read' from a database table (tblSysReg) and generates an automation error.

The successfull ODBC connection parameters are as follows:

- Type: TCP/IP
- Server: 10.0.0.3
- Port: 1433

I am logging in as 'sa' with my SQL Server password for SQL Server on Linux.

I am battling to understand how the connection test is successful, bit the program using the connection cannot read from any tables in the SQL Server database on Linux?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you post the connection string that you're using in your application, as well as the specific error you receive?

Comment: The application was developed using Visual Basic 6. The code used to access the database object is as follows: 

Dim rec1 As ADODB.Recordset
Set rec1 = New ADODB.Recordset
rec1.Open "Select * from tblSysReg", gstrDefaultDB, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

This is where the error is generated as follows:
automation error code  -2147217843

Comment: gstrDefaultDB is the string containing the name of the ODBC registered and tested connection. The connection test credentials are: system administrator (sa) and password. The connection is set to use SQL Server Authentication,

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server ODBC Driver Version 06.01.7601

Running connectivity tests...

Attempting connection
Connection established
Verifying option settings
Disconnecting from server

TESTS COMPLETED SUCCESSFULLY!

(Connection from Windows client to Linux hosting SQL Server achieved.)

Comment: You can edit your question to add those bits in.  Makes it easier to read.

Comment: Thanks will do ...

Comment: Cool.  I just did some minor formatting of the code block.  Oh, and welcome to Stackoverflow! :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code in your comments, you are trying to pass the connection string to `rec1.Open()` instead of a connection object.  You need to use a Connection object to open the connection to the database and then use that object when opening the Recordset.

Something like this

```
Dim conn as ADODB.Connection
Dim rec1 As ADODB.Recordset

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rec1 = New ADODB.Recordset

conn.Open gstrDefaultDB
rec1.Open "Select * from tblSysReg", conn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
... [do more stuff] ...
rec1.Close
conn.Close
```

You can also use the `Execute` method on the `Connection` to return a recordset.

```
Dim conn as ADODB.Connection
Dim rec1 As ADODB.Recordset

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection

conn.Open gstrDefaultDB
Set rec1 = conn.Execute("Select * from tblSysReg")
... [do more stuff] ...
rec1.Close
conn.Close
```

Have a look at this page for a lot more examples:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/168336/how-to-open-ado-connection-and-recordset-objects

Comment: I will follow your advice and reply. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you so much, your simple yet effective solution has enabled me to finalize the migration to Linux for SQL Server on Windows .....

Comment: Excellent!  Good luck :)

Comment: I would like to mention that the performance of our new SQL Server 'server' hosted on Linux is outstanding, and the entire exercise was well worth the effort. We are also now planning to roll out to much larger clients due to this efficiency.